# MouseDown event on a custom UserControl located on a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, mousedown

I'm trying to implement a drag/drop in my application. I need to be able to grab a `UserControl` (in my case `PipelineTask`) that I programatically added to a `FlowLayoutPanel` (which in it's turn is located inside a `TabPage`).

The method where I add my `PipelineTask` to the `FlowLayoutPanels`:

```
private void fillPipeline()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        flowLayoutPanelNonIssues.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (FullTask task in pipelineTasks)
        {
            PipelineTask ts = new PipelineTask(task);
            ts.MouseDown += ts_MouseDown;
            if (task.TaskType == "Driver Issue")
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ts);
            }
            else
            {
                flowLayoutPanelNonIssues.Controls.Add(ts);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `MouseDown` method:

```
private void ts_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PipelineTask ts = sender as PipelineTask;
        ts.DoDragDrop(ts, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

But the `MouseDown` event is not firing at all.
My `UserControl` has a `Panel` on it that fills the whole `UserControl` and I'm guessing this might be the issue. 
Is there anyone who can help me on this? If I am right about the above a solution on how to deal with this and grab the `UserControl` instead will do fine too. 
Thanks

**EDIT**

I temporarely fixed the issue by removing the panel that was filling up my UserControl. So obviously this was the problem. However, a solution to this would be nice without having to remove the panel.

Comment: Could anyone tell me why my question gets downvoted twice?

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the Panel's MouseDown and raise a custom event that you'd be creating on the UserControl, which in turn gets handled by ts_MouseDown...

Comment: That's what I thought would fix the issue too, if I needed it. Too bad you can't just set a property to a Parent to handle mouse events from a child control. Thanks for your help

Comment: So what's the solution in the end of 2019?